# Find all occurrences of a divided substring in a string

Tags: java, python, regex, algorithm

I'm trying to solve a little extraordinary problem. I need to find the amount all occurrences of a substring in a string if the substring don't have to be in one piece.

---

### Example:

#### Input:

```
adnndaend
```

I'll try to find the substring **and**.

#### Occurrences:

**a**d**n**n**d**aend

**a**dn**nd**aend

**a**d**n**ndaen**d**

**a**dn**n**daen**d**

**a**dnndae**nd**

adnnd**a**e**nd**

#### Output:

```
6
```

---

I've tried to achieve the list of occurences by using python **re.findall**:

```
re.findall('^.*a.*n.*d.*$', 'adnndaend')
```

but it returns the list with just one item - the whole string:

```
['adnndaend']
```

So could you, please, tell me, what's wrong with my regex or show me your better solution? Ideally in Python or Java, I'm not very familiar with other languages.

Comment: `re.findall` only returns none-overlapping matches. So for example, your fist two occurrences would not both be returned as the same `a` and `d` is found in both.

Comment: this isn't going to work with regex, because regex either gives you a lazy (i.e. *?) or greedy (i.e. *) response, never anything in between unless you specifically ask for it (e.g. *{3}), which would mean you would have to try many variants of the same regex, which would be very inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get all combinations of using the amount of times a, n and d appear:

```
from itertools import combinations
def sub_s(st,word):
   all_s = (x for x in st if x in word)
   return len([x for x in (combinations(all_s, len(word))) if "".join(x) == word] )
```

Answer (score 2):

Regex returns non-overlapping matches, which in your case is only a single one. So regex is out of the question. Instead, I came up with this little recursive function:

```
def count(haystack, needle):
    result= 0
    pos= -1
    char= needle[0] # we'll be searching the haystack for all occurences of this character.

    while True:
        # find the next occurence
        pos= haystack.find(char, pos+1)

        # if there are no more occurences, we're done
        if pos==-1:
            return result

        # once we found the first character, recursively count the occurences of
        # needle (without the first character) in what's left of haystack
        if len(needle)==1:
            result+= 1
        else:
            result+= count(haystack[pos+1:], needle[1:])
```

I didn't test it extensively, but:

```
>>> print count('adnndaend', 'and')
6
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public int findOccurrences(String str, String key) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == key.charAt(0)) {
            if (key.length() > 1) {
                total += findOccurrences(str.substring(i), key.substring(1));
            } else {
                total += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return total;
}

@Test
public void yup(){
    System.out.println(findOccurrences("adnndaend", "and"));
}
```

Output = 6

Answer (score 1):

You could use [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) as follows:

```
import itertools
pattern = "and"
print len([''.join(i) for i in itertools.combinations('adnndaend',len(pattern) if ''.join(i) == pattern])
```

output:

```
6
```

idea is Generate all combinations of characters sequence using `itertools.combinations` and match them against your pattern; resulting list would have only matched items.

Comment: Please use `len(pattern)` instead of `3`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have only one problem - the second 'join' causes the 'Invalid syntax' error. Is it only my problem or is it some mistake in this code? I must admit, that I don't see any :D

Comment: i have validated the code in my machine..it was fine...there should be something wrong while you copy...